# How to scrape html tags with no classes and changing id using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape the sold price of property from http://house.speakingsame.com/p.php?q=Brisbane+City&sta=qld

It has no formatting, no classes and the content is represented in tables.
[image]

[image]

what should I do in this case? Each table represents each property. I need the sold price for each property and hence each table.

`response.css('tbody').getall()`returns nothing at all.

Comment: Grab the tables directly with `pandas.read_html(response.text)`, then you can grab all the data from the tables stored as `DataFrames` and not worry about the id changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using xpath you could use:

```py
for element in response.xpath("//table//table//table"):
    sold = element.xpath(".//b")[0].xpath("./text()").get()
    print(sold)
    date = element.xpath(".//td")[0].xpath("./text()").get()
```

output:

```
Sold $640,000
Sold $640,000
Sold $320,000
Sold $320,000
Sold $145,000
Sold $145,000
Sold $145,000
Sold $145,000
Sold $239,000
Sold $239,000
Sold $695,000
Sold $695,000
Sold $740,000
Sold $740,000
Sold $375,000
Sold $375,000
Sold $390,000
Sold $390,000
Sold $695,000
Sold $695,000
```

Comment: Hi thanks, what if I don't want the bold? and just want the text (the date) instead. Is ```[0]``` the table row?

Comment: @CountDOOKU  I edited the code so it includes the xpath for the date.  they are very similar you just get the text for the parent node instead.

Comment: Hi Alexpdex, thanks. The thing is that ``[0]``` is fixed to table row number 1. What if the sold price is in say table row number 5 for some reasons?

Comment: @CountDOOKU Then you would have change the xpath.  I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @countDOOKU  could you please explain with an example so I know what you are referring to?